# Perl does not reevaluate regex variable

Tags: regex, perl

I am in charge of upgrading this Perl script from Perl v5.6.1 (2001) to v5.20.2 (2015). I have these 2 regex variable:

```
foreach (@filelist) {
    chomp;
    my $File = $_;
    if ( $File =~ qr/.+/o ) {
        if ( $BaseLine ) {

            $BaseLineRegExpA = qr/^\Q$BaseLine\E\\/io; #these 2 regexes
            $BaseLineRegExpB = qr/^\Q$BaseLine\E;/io;  #these 2 regexes

            if ( $File =~ /$BaseLineRegExpA/ ) {
                #...

            } elsif ( (!($File =~ /$BaseLineRegExpB/)) && (!(lc( $File ) eq lc( $BaseLine ) )) ) {
                $BaseLine = $File;
            }
        }
     }
}
```

So, I have 2 questions:

1. In the old Perl version, the `$BaseLineRegExpA` and `$BaseLineRegExpB` gets reevaluate every time `$BaseLine` changes, but in the new Perl, it does not. How do I make it changes? I've tried my `$BaseLineRegExpA`, it still does not change.
2. In the old Perl, `$BaseLineRegExpA` evals to: `(?i-xsm:^F:\\dd\\)`, and in the new Perl, it evals to `(?^i:^F:\\dd\\)`. My questions is, is there a different between `?i-xsm:^` and `?^i:^`?

Thanks so much, unfortunately, these are legacy scripts and I don't know much about Perl.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The `o` modifier prevents re-evaluating variables substituted into regexes. It's curious that it didn't happen for you on 5.6, but it's probably because `qr` was still new in that version. Removing it (changing `/io` to `/i`) should make things work the way you expect.
2. The `(?i-xsm)` encodes the regex modifier flags that are in effect (`i` is turned on, `x`, `s`, and `m` are turned off). Sometime around perl 5.14, Perl got some new regex modifier flags, which would change the stringification of all regexes. Since this was already a backwards-incompatible change, it was decided to do it in a way that would limit the hassle caused by adding any new flags down the road, and so the `^` character was used to represent the "default" set of flags. So `(?^i)` means "the default flags, plus the `i` flag". They both mean basically the same thing, and there's nothing you should worry about.

Comment: Tested. qr//o was definitely broken in 5.6. The o was ignored.

Comment: @NamNgo you're welcome. Just as  side note, I've been using Perl for 15 years and there isn't *anyplace* I would recommend using `/o`. At best it makes a very small performance improvement, easily outweighed by its potential for creating bugs.